# TeamCity Build Report Tab Start Page

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm having trouble getting a report showing.

I have the following artifact path

```
gatling.zip
```

That contains this structure

```
\gatling.zip
 -\gatling
   -\runtest-120501032019
     -index.html
```

The folder that contains the numbers, will always change depending on data. 
So I'm trying to use some wildcards in teamcity to get the index.html from the folder regardless of it's name.

But I can't get it working. In the build report tab start page I've tried a range of different ways but the index.html
is never found in the Gatling build report tab.

I'm trying something like this

```
gatling.zip!**/**/index.html
```

Can anyone give some advice on how to get this working? Thanks!

Comment: I have also tried being more specific and doing gatling.zip!gatling/runtimeparameters-**/index.html but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Answered over on the teamcity support forums;

I'm afraid that wildcards aren't supported. In this scenario, a possible solution would be to export the path as a build parameter, then reference this parameter on the report path. For build-scoped reports, the parameters will be resolved in the context of the build and that should work.

If you can't report them automatically, simply add a build step that exports the parameter using a build message: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-AddingorChangingaBuildParameter